# Deprecated tags in html5

Tags: html, xhtml

I am using using html5 for building web page. I am able to use html5 tags. I want to know whether i can use tags of html which are deprecated in html5 like `<ul>` tag.

**Edit (rectifying a typo):** I meant the `<u>` tag.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that `<ul>` is deprecated in HTML5?

Comment: I have a feeling you might have meant `<u>`, in which case, you can use CSS instead.

Comment: If you do mean `<u>` then you should use something that doesn't look like a link instead. :)

Comment: Yes, the OP has rectified the harsh typo. However, the correction was made after 4 (out of the 5 currently existing Answers in this thread) had been posted, causing inconsistencies in most of the answers here at present, thereby confusing the visitors. Assuming these consequences were unintentional, I have appended the affected posts with a corresponding indicator from this Question's edit history.

Comment: Aside, I have not done this to support making drastic edits to one's Question that refutes existing Answers without getting flagged/reported causing more repairing work for others. Hopefully, receiving the resultant edit notification will encourage the respective authors to update their answers as deemed appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Some elements that are deprecated in HTML 4.x / XHTML 1.x are acceptable in [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), some are [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete); you would need to [check them](http://validator.w3.org/) on a case-by-case basis (noting that HTML 5 is still a draft and thus a moving target).

> deprecated in html5 like `<ul>` tag

`<ul>` has never been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The tags `<acronym>`, `<applet>`, `<basefont>`, `<big>`, `<center>`, `<dir>`, `<font>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<noframes>`, `<isindex>`, `<strike>`, `<tt>` aren't used anymore in **HTML5**. They aren't deprecated, but you'd better not use them ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements)).

You can also check absent attributes: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#absent-attributes.

Comment: w3schools is not a very good source for information, specifically if it regards recently updated specs. See http://w3fools.com/ for more info.

Comment: Well, I changed to links to the w3 original source, which list the exact same tags. ;) it was just the first link I found, and without an original source (found later), I thought it was better than nothing.

Comment: @Entropy - The list is not the same. If you check, you will see the the w3c list does not include the `u` element, while the w3schools one does. w3schools is wrong as usual.

Comment: @Alohci - While w3schools has problems, it's not "wrong as usual" in most cases. It's now popular to make fun of it due to the w3fools site. In most cases, it's fine for a quick look up. In fact, I just now found my own issue with w3fools.

Comment: @Rob - People were heavily criticising (or making fun of) w3schools long before w3fools came along. In fact, w3fools has it's own problems - "Named anchors have been deprecated since HTML4". Nope, they weren't deprecated until XHTML 1.0. And w3fools only touches on a narrow range of the problems that afflict w3schools, and sometimes their criticisms are dubious at best. W3Schools has put in a small amount of effort to correct the most glaring of errors, but has a long, long way still to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `<u>` tag in html 5 even though it is deprecated. Using CSS to achieve the same effect is however recommended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>Can we use deprecated html 4 elements in html 5?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is a <u>test</u>.
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use the W3C validator to validate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> deprecated in html5 like `<ul>` tag

`<ul>` is not deprecated, you can find some lists of deprecated elements and their replacements like [this one](http://www.webbyzone.com/2011/02/27/deprecated-tags-in-html5/), just try to google little bit more :-)

Answer (score 0):

> deprecated in html5 like `<ul>` tag

The `<ul>` tag will not be deprecated. you can see all the changes [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff), and the tags that will be dropped [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#absent-elements). Nothing will be "deprecated" (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#backwards-compatible)), as :

> Since HTML5 has separate conformance requirements for authors and user agents there is no longer a need for marking features "deprecated".

so keep on using your `<ul>`! (If you actually *have* an unsorted list... if not, use the element that's most suited for the job)